# automating asp.net testing

Tags: asp.net, unit-testing, automated-tests

I have to test almost 20 asp.net web application everyday morning to ensure there is no issue in the web sites. so is ther any option to automate it ? There is data entry involved like entering username,password etc.

Note: I will not have the access to the code(only to the applicaiton URL).

Please suggest some option for this, so that we can avoid the manual effort involved in this. Thanks.

Regards,
Jebli.

Answer (score 2):

You should look into web automation tools like [WatiN](http://watin.org/) or Selenium.

From the WatiN documentation:

```
[Test]  
 public void SearchForWatiNOnGoogle() 

{

  using (var browser = new IE("http://www.google.com"))  
  {  
     browser.TextField(Find.ByName("q")).TypeText("WatiN");    
     browser.Button(Find.ByName("btnG")).Click();            
     Assert.IsTrue(browser.ContainsText("WatiN"));            
  }       
}
```

From the [Selenium](http://seleniumhq.org/docs/03_webdriver.html) Documentation:

```
using OpenQA.Selenium.Firefox;
using OpenQA.Selenium;

class GoogleSuggest
{

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        IWebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();

        //Notice navigation is slightly different than the Java version
        //This is because 'get' is a keyword in C#
        driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("http://www.google.com/");
        IWebElement query = driver.FindElement(By.Name("q"));
        query.SendKeys("Cheese");
        System.Console.WriteLine("Page title is: " + driver.Title);
        driver.Quit();
    }

}
```

WatiN and Selenium are Open Source

Comment: is it licenced tool ? Can you please share any links which has the sampled ?

Answer (score 0):

VSTT 2010 is a good bet.

Example demos
How To: Functional Testing Automation Using Visual Studio 2010 - http://blogs.msdn.com/b/syedab/archive/2010/01/13/how-to-functional-testing-automation-using-visual-studio-2010.aspx

Data Driving Coded UI Tests - http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mathew_aniyan/archive/2009/03/17/data-driving-coded-ui-tests.aspx